# Discord.py Uploading Random Images

Tags: python, discord

Not sure if its the lack of coffee, but I'm having a slight issue with uploading random images.

```
@client.command(aliases=['cuddle'])
async def _cuddle(ctx, *, user):
        image= [
            'file_1.gif',
            'file_2.gif',
            'file_3.gif',
            'file_4.gif',
            'file_5.gif',
            'file_6.gif',
            'file_7.gif']

        await ctx.send(f'You got a Cuddle from{ctx.message.author.mention}, {user}!\n {random.choice(file =discord.file(image))}')
```

its mostly the

```
{random.choice(file =discord.file(image))}
```

ive tryed
 discord.file'file_1.gif', method but with no prevail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it for anyone who wants to know

```
import os

@commands.command(aliases=['image'])
    async def images(self, ctx):
        image = os.listdir('./cogs/image/')
        imgString = random.choice(image)  # Selects a random element from the list
        path = "./cogs/image/" + imgString
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(path))
```